# Excess memory usage swift

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, self-reference

I'm building a today extension for iOS and I'm confused why this function keeps on using more and more memory.

See the code below:

```
func loadActivePlayer() {
    kodi.getActivePlayer {
        (response) in
        let result = JSON(response)

        let activePlayer = ActivePlayer()

        if let playerid = result["result"][0]["playerid"].int {
            activePlayer.playerid = playerid
        }

        if let type = result["result"][0]["type"].string {
            activePlayer.type = type
        }

        if(activePlayer.isEmpty()) {
            self.loadActivePlayer()
        }
        else {
            self.enablePlaybackButtons(true)
            self.activePlayer = activePlayer

            self.kodi.getItem(activePlayer.playerid) {
                (response) in
                var result = JSON(response)
                var item = Item()

                if let id = result["result"]["item"]["id"].int {
                    item.id = id
                }

                if let type = result["result"]["item"]["type"].string {
                    item.type = type
                }

                if let label = result["result"]["item"]["label"].string {
                    item.label = label
                }

                if let title = result["result"]["item"]["title"].string {
                    item.title = title
                }

                if let season = result["result"]["item"]["season"].int {
                    item.season = season
                }

                if let episode = result["result"]["item"]["episode"].int {
                    item.episode = episode
                }

                if let showtitle = result["result"]["item"]["showtitle"].string {
                    item.showtitle = showtitle
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.itemTitleLabel.text = item.title
                    self.itemShowTitleLabel.text = item.showtitle
                    self.itemSeasonEpisodeLabel.text = "S\(item.season)E\(item.episode)"
                }

                self.loadActivePlayer()
            }
        }
    }
```

When it goes in the if(activePlayer.isEmpty())
the memory usage increases and increases and increases, quite irritating.

But when it goes into the else, the memory usage stays almost the same, it does not increase significantly.

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: How do you know it "uses more and more memory"? Also, if this is happening when loading an ActivePlayer, what _is_ an ActivePlayer? Is it part of some third-party library? If so, there may be nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Whilst debugging I switched to the "Debug Navigator" tab instead of the Project navigator and saw the memory usage. ActivePlayer is a simple class that has 2 properties: playerid and type, and a function that returns a bool if the properties are not filled (isEmpty())

Comment: Don't believe what it says. Swift memory management in the debugger is totally misleading. Use only Instruments, and only on the device, to study Swift memory usage. Trust me on this one.

Comment: Alright, didn't know that. I don't have a developers license yet, so I can't debug on my device yet. Anyway, thank you.